# Regex match string for all valid doctype tags

Tags: regex

I need a regex string that can catch all valid doctype tags. 
I've tried `/(<!doctype )html+\s*(>)?/g/` and `/(<!doctype )html+\s*(>)(.+)?/g/` but both of them keep missing the point. :(

```js
const valid1 = `<!doctype html>`
const valid2 = `<!doctype html     >`
const valid3 = `<!doctype html     >
                <p></p>`
const invalid1 = `<!doctype htmlfoobar>`
const invalid2 = `<!doctype htmlfoobar>abcd`
```

Comment: Why do you need a regex? What language is it?

Comment: Try `<!doctype\s+html[\s>]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this solved it for me nicely....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
<!doctype\s+html[\s>]
```

**Details**

- `<!doctype` - a literal string
- `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
  -`html` - a literal string
- `[\s>]` - either a whitespace or a `>`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DrLlOF/1).

Answer (score 2):

What about this one:

```
awk '/<!doctype +html *>/ { print "ok";}'
<!doctype html>
ok
<!doctype html     >
ok
<!doctype html     >
ok
                <p></p>
<!doctype htmlfoobar>
<!doctype htmlfoobar>abcd
```